# How to make local jars being found by maven when running tests

Tags: java, maven

My unit test of the maven project is doing `Class.forName` to detect specific classes exist or not during testing.

I have the third-party local jars containing those specific classes.

How could I let maven (or ClassLoader) to know where to find those local third-party jars during testing?

Thank you.

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-to-a-maven-project

Comment: Not really, I dont really care about the compile time behaviour. I just need the class loader to find the jar in run time.

Comment: I would install them into the local repository and add them as test dependencies.